# Unable to update column in Oracle 10g table having the name "PURPOSE"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00904

Trying to update an oracle 10g table using asp.net and the oracleclient connector

Here is the sql syntax:

```
UPDATE tableX set PURPOSE = 'T' where REQUEST_ID = '2543'
```

This throws an error:

```
ORA-00904: "PURPOSE": invalid identifier
```

If I try to update a different column

```
UPDATE tableX set DELIVERY_COMMENTS = 'T' where REQUEST_ID = '2543'
```

everything works fine.

The column PURPOSE does exist and I am able to INSERT information into the PURPOSE column.

Anyone have any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Can you post the results of running `desc tableX` in SQL*Plus or `SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'TABLEX'`?  Is there any chance someone has created a case-sensitive column name for the PURPOSE column?

Comment: The results of select column_name etc..... is a listing of the column names and PURPOSE is listed. The funny thing is, is if run the update sql cmd using TOAD it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think PURPOSE is a resreved word but if it is it must be surrounded by double quotes" `set "PURPOSE" = 'T'`.

The column name may be lower case or mixed case. Run `select * from tableX where rownum < 2` and see what SqlPlus says the column name is. The definitive way to determine the case of the column name is

`select c.owner, c.column_id, c.column_name
     from all_tab_cols c
     where c.table_name = 'TABLEX'
     order by  c.owner, c.column_id`

Notice that 'TABLEX' is all uppercase. If PURPOSE is not all uppercase it must be surrounded by double quotes so that Oracle treats it case sensitive.

Comment: The results are that the column name is UPPERCASE.

Comment: Did you try my first suggestion, surrounding it with double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Ok...here is the answer

OPERATOR ERROR

I was connecting to the database as user2, which put me in the user2 schema. user2 schema has a view using user1.target_table named user2.target_table. The problem was that the view was setup like

"Select field1, field2 from user1.target_table"

A new field was added to user1.target_table but the view in user2 schema was not updated to reflect the change.

I discovered the error by fully qualifying the UPDATE statement to

UPDATE user1.target_table set PURPOSE = 'T' where field1 = '1'

the update statement worked like a champ.

Lesson learned.....don't create a view in one schema with a name that is used in another schema.

Hope this clarifies my PEBKAC (problem exists between keyboard and chair)

Comment: To reinforce the point, if you do a CREATE VIEW ...  AS SELECT * FROM ..., it implicitly turns that * into the list of columns at the time of view creation. So the view will NOT automatically include any new columns added to the table. In that case, use a synonym.